# HTML components using Typescript, Knockout and Require - HTML is not rendered?

Tags: html, typescript, knockout.js, components, requirejs

I am trying to learn how component driven development works and I have followed the documents here https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html (Including the many nested links relevant to this topic) however although the TS/JS files are loaded without error the HTML component is never rendered.

Here you can see the the typescript is loaded correctly by RequireJS:

[Login-User typescript loaded in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVB72.png)

And here is the HTML component in the webpage:

[HTML component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkGoe.png)

This is the content within the HTML 'template':

```
<div class="panel">
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="Value: $component.Username()" />
    <br />
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="Value: $component.Password()" />
    <br />
    <label>Valid:</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="Value: $component.ValidUser()" />
</div>
```

Here is the registration of the HTML template:

```
const componentName = "Login-User";
ko.components.unregister(componentName);
ko.components.register(componentName, {
    viewModel: LoginViewModel,
    template: { require: `text!/Views/Components/${componentName}.html` }
});
```

I do not get any errors in the console but the constructor in the TS file is never hit when adding breakpoints to debug which suggests the me that there was no attempt to actually render the HTML component at all?

I have checked all file paths are correct and deleted and re-compiled the TS files to generate JS files to ensure everything is up to date, I assume I have not properly configured require in some way and so the HTML component is never actually registered however due to no errors being logged I am a bit stuck for where to go next! As I said previously I have read the documentation on Knockout and also for RequireJS however when searching google for issue when implementing a HTML component I seem to only get results for Angular.

Any advice on how to determine the issue would be greatly appreciated, even better if there is any documentation/guides on how to use Knockout/Require/Typescript/HTML Components together which someone could point me at that would be great!

I think I have provided everything need but if not let me know.

Thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 0):

Okay after a couple more hours of trial and error I figured out I had a few problems, for anyone else having this issue try the below resolutions:

1. I was not calling ko.applybindings();

```
import * as ko from "knockout";

export default class LoginViewModel {
    Username: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    Password: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    ValidUser: KnockoutComputed<boolean>;

    constructor(username: string, password: string) {
        this.Username = ko.observable(username);
        this.Password = ko.observable(password);

        this.computedMethods();
    }

    private computedMethods(): void {
        this.ValidUser = ko.pureComputed(() => {
            return this.Username() === "Danny" && this.Password() === "pasword";
        });
    }
}

const componentName = "login-user";
ko.components.register(componentName, {
    viewModel: LoginViewModel,
    template: { require: `text!Scripts/Typescript/${componentName}.html` }
});

ko.applyBindings(); << This is important as it actually binds the custom element i.e login-user params="username: 'Danny', password: 'none'"></login-user> and without it nothing will be rendered on the page
```

2. After correcting this issue I then got a 404 in console when trying to load the custom element and although the filepath was correct I found that the best way to resolve this was to have the custom element in the same folder as it's TS counter-part:

```
Before:
template: { require: `text!/Views/Components/${componentName}.html` }

After:
template: { require: `text!Scripts/Typescript/${componentName}.html` }
```

1. Google searches recommended installing the following nuget packages although I think only require.text is actually required, if it doesn't resolve your issue it's worth a shot..:
   [Require Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ142.png)

4. I initially had my components named using camel case i.e Login-User.ts and Login-User.html, I read somewhere that they should be lower case to be valid html 'Tags' and both the .ts and .html files should be named exactly the same

Hope this helps anyone else having issues.